# access denied to existing files on osx share

Tags: windows-7, macos, smb

My computer, Mac1 (Mountain Lion), has smb share Share1 that is browsable from computer Win1 (Windows 7).

Mac1\User1 is the user account on Mac1 and has rw permissions on Share1. From Win1, User1 can create new folders and files.

PROBLEM: User1 cannot read existing files in Share1 ("Access Denied. Contact Administrator"). I've even set perms on share to EVERYONE RW.

Running `ls -le` on Share1 returns:

```
1: user:user1 allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

How do I allow User1 to rw permsissions Recursively throughout the Share1 filesystem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! Changing the owner of the filesystem Share1 to User1 worked. From within the parent dir of Share1 on Mac1, I ran the following command:

sudo chown -Rv user1 share1